# HTTPS request to avatars.io returns HTTP url that causes 'Mixed Content' error

Tags: javascript, avatars.io

I'm trying to deal with [avatars.io JS lib](https://github.com/chute/avatars-io-js). I want to send HTTP/HTTPS requests based on current page protocol.

When I send HTTPS request to avatars.io service, like this https://avatars.io/v1/upload?authorization=...
I got response http://s3.amazonaws.com/cdn.getchute.com/v1/images/avatars.io/avatar-32.png

And this causes 'Mixed Content' error.

Also there is a question: how I can change the host before uploader initialization to prevent unwanted requests to default host?